# OpenGL ES 2.0 GLSL texture2D return value when unbound

Tags: opengl-es, return, default, shader, textures

In the following code:

```
gl_FragColor = vColor * texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate);
```

I noticed the default value returned by texture2D is a white (1,1,1,1) if u_Texture is unbound.

Is it safe to base my shader on this fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't have thought so.

I have seen other instances where the default value has been black. It could theoretically be any colour in the case where the memory used by the sampler is a section of uninitialised  video memory, it depends on the opengl implementation

Comment: So, can it be any value or does it depend on the opengl implementation?

Comment: Yes it depends on the opengl implementation