# OpenGL Sampling with no texture bound

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

When sampling a texture in GLSL like this:

```
vec4 color = texture(mySampler, myCoords);
```

If there is no texture bound to *mySampler*, *color* seems to be always (0, 0, 0, 1).

Is this the standard behavior? Or may it be *undefined* on some implementations? I couldn't find anything in the specs.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570379/opengl-es-2-0-glsl-texture2d-return-value-when-unbound.  I couldn't find anything in the spec either but as far as I know it's undefined.  I've certainly seen it do different things in different implementations!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's really no such thing as being "unbound" -- you're simply bound to the initial texture object which is known as texture 0.  According to the OpenGL wiki (http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Objects),

```
You are strongly encouraged to think of texture 0 as a non-existent texture.
```

Ultimately, the value you're going to get in the shader depends on what happens to be in Texture Object 0 at the time.  I can't really find anything except one [forum post](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/174060-texture2d-and-disabled-texturing) that actually says what this should be:

```
The texture 0 represents an actual texture object, the default texture.
All textures start out as 1x1 white textures.
```

I certainly wouldn't trust that to be consistent across all GPU drivers, yours might have it initialized to all zero, or it might be considered an incomplete texture, in which case the OpenGL spec (2.0 and later at least) says:

```
If a fragment shader uses a sampler whose associated texture object is not
complete, the texture image unit will return (R, G, B, A) = (0, 0, 0, 1).
```

... So really the wisest course of action seems to be "don't do that."  Make sure you have a valid (non-zero id) texture bound if you're going to run a sampler.

Comment: Actually I tested only with a vec3 (and it was (0,0,0)) so maybe the last component was in fact a 1.

Comment: I would feel more comfortable with a quote from the actual specifications instead of opengl.org's wiki but that's still better that what I found on my own. Thanks.

Comment: @JeremyLaumon Yeah I looked through the spec and couldn't find it :(  Maybe somebody else can.

Comment: "*the OpenGL spec (2.0 and later at least) says:*" FYI: this language was revised and updated in 4.5. You only get (0,0,0,1) for floating-point samplers and 0 for shadow samplers. You get undefined values for integer samplers.

Comment: It's also important to note that OpenGL and OpenGL ES are *different* specifications, which can have different behavior. I wouldn't be surprised if ES made it strictly undefined.

Answer (score 5):

Nathan is correct (but I am too new/reputation too low to upvote).

I have /certainly/ seen that on some OpenGL ES platforms, using an unbound texture will render garbage on the screen (random contents of graphics memory).  You can't trust all driver vendors to follow the spec.

Never, ever, reference un-bound OpenGL objects or state.