# OpenGL/GLSL Runtime Error Handling

Tags: opengl, runtime-error, glsl

*This is a general question. I did not find any resources on the net about this, but I think it's worth documenting somewhere.*

How exactly are Shader Runtime (not compile Errors) handled, say if one is trying to access a uniform that has the value Null currently?

Is the thread just being aborted? Will garbage values be produced? Is it drivers/ hardwaredependant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For "normal" uniform variables I don't see any possibility how they could cause a runtime error. Since they are all of primitive types, a value like NULL is not possible. All of these variables are initialized at link time. The specification tells:

> 2.15.3.1
>
> All uniform variables are read-only and are initialized externally either at link
>   time or through the API. The link-time initial value is either the value of the variable's initializer, if
>   present, or 0 if no initializer is present.

But there are two other types of uniforms that could be of interest here:

**Sampler Uniforms**

Samplers are initialized to zero also, which means they point to texture 0. According to the OpenGL Specification:

> 8.1
>
> The name space for texture
>   objects is the unsigned integers, with zero reserved by the GL to represent
>   the default texture object. The default texture object is bound to each of the
>   TEXTURE_1D, TEXTURE_2D, TEXTURE_3D, TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY, TEXTURE_-
>   2D_ARRAY, TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, TEXTURE_BUFFER, TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,
>   TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY, TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, and TEXTURE_-
>   2D_MULTISAMPLE_ARRAY targets during context initialization.

This basically means, that it is also impossible here to generate any runtime exception. The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020058/opengl-sampling-with-no-texture-bound) indicate what happens when reading from texture 0.

**Uniform Blocks**

Meaning uniforms backed by UBO or SSBO storage. This seems according to:

> If any active uniform block is not backed by a sufficiently
>       large buffer object, the results of shader execution are undefined, and
>       may result in GL interruption or termination.

be implementation dependent.

**Conclusion**

The only way to get runtime exceptions in a shader seems to be when a uniform block tries to access a variable that is not backed by a buffer. As far as I know, one can do nothing to handle such situations inside the shader.

[GLSL 4.5 Specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.50.diff.pdf)

[OpenGL 4.5 Specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec45.core.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

GLSL does not have pointers, so a `uniform` cannot be NULL. Every `uniform` has a value.

If a shader attempts to read from a buffer (uniform, SSBO, atomic counter) which does not have an object bound to the corresponding binding point, then... well, the specification is kinda unclear on this. The 4.5 specification says:

> When executing shaders that access uniform blocks, the binding point corresponding to each active uniform block must be populated with a buffer object ...

What happens when "must" is violated is unclear. It could just be "undefined behavior". It could be a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error.

A later part of that paragraph says:

> If any active uniform block is not backed by a sufficiently large buffer object, the results of shader execution may be undefined or modified, as described in section 6.4.

SSBOs and atomic counters say similar things, also referring to section 6.4. But it's not clear that binding nothing is the same as not having a "sufficiently large buffer object" bound.

Section 6.4 refers to *anything* which could access outside the bound range of a buffer object. It says:

> Any command which does not detect these attempts, and performs such an invalid read or write, has undefined results, and may result in GL interruption or termination.

Shader processing is among the things that do not seem to "detect these attempts". So we must assume that it is at least possible to meet the dreaded "GPU reset".

However, if you turn on robustness, then this all goes away. You're guaranteed that any such accesses will merely return undefined values, and it explicitly says:

> will not result in GL interruption or termination.

So that's good.

For samplers, things are different. You can't really unbind textures; you only bind texture object 0. And texture object 0 is a functional texture object (technically, it's *many* functional textures). So your shader can try to read from it.

However, if you never allocate images in texture object 0, then they are also *incomplete* textures. And the specification say:

> If a sampler is used in a shader and the sampler’s associated texture is not
>   complete, as defined in section 8.17, (0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0), in floating-point, will be returned for a non-shadow sampler and 0 for a shadow sampler. In this case, if the sampler is declared in the shader as a signed or unsigned integer sampler type, undefined values are returned as specified in section 9.9(“Texture Functions”) of the OpenGL Shading Language Specification when the texture format and sampler type are unsupported combinations.

So you get well-defined values for floating point samplers, but undefined values for integer samplers. Also, sampler query functions (querying the size or number of mipmaps) return undefined values, as stated in GLSL.

But none of these say that program termination is a possibility, so it *isn't* a possibility. So you're safe.

[Images](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Load_Store) are a bit more complex. Images have no "image object 0"; that's genuinely "not an object".

However, GLSL 4.50 says:

> If the image target type does not match the bound image in this manner, if the data type does not match the bound image, or if the format layout qualifier does not match the image unit format as described in section 8.25 “Texture Image Loads and Stores” of the OpenGL Specification, the results of image accesses are undefined but cannot include program termination.

We must assume that "not an image" doesn't match the image's data type, so while you will get undefined values, you *won't* get program termination.

The only other thing shaders can do that could be considered a hard error would be an infinite loop. This is detected in the simplest way possible: every shader is expected to execute for no more than X instructions (where X is decided by the hardware). If it tries to execute more than X, then it is assumed to have entered an infinite loop, so the GPU is reset.

Another thing that could kill your GPU is this:

```
int i[5] = ...;

for( int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
    i[j] = 10;
```

Whether it does or not is implementation dependent. This also includes dynamically accessing elements of a vector or matrix. Note that robustness again ensures that these accesses will not crash the GPU (or read/write other memory).

Here are some shader processes that will result in undefined values, but not blowing up the GPU:

- Accessing from an [Array Texture](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture), if the layer index you provide is larger than the number of layers in the texture.
- Using floating point Inf or NaN in computations.

Comment: Very nice answer, seems complete too. +1