# Strange kernel artifacts when writing to fragment out often

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, artifacts

I'm developing a game engine and working on a deferred rendering pipeline. After finishing the (second pass) (shading) shader, I started testing the pipeline on various other computers I have. Interestingly, on my older laptop I get this strange artifacting on each 4x8 pixel group (example below). It looks like the shader is executing and ultimately returning the correct color, but in a very random fashion.

This question is not a bug report or a solution request. I have fixed this issue with the below code patch. This thread is rather to gather a better understanding as why this happens, and to provide insights for anyone else that may be affected by the same issue.

[image: Resulting image with artifacts]
To describe the effect in more detail:
About 50% of the screen has a 4x8 group of pixels that highly tint the actual resulting color.
These 4x8 groups in random places on the screen each frame, causing a "static" effect.
Certain models tint different colours. As you can see below, the reflective bunny is tinted blue however the refractive spheres are tinted yellow. This doesn't seem to be a Gbuffer issue however as they both sample from the same texture which I'm sure is correct (as I can see it on screen at the same time).
Different object's 4x8 blocks have a higher rate of showing the correct color. You can see the refractive bunny is mostly correct, but the reflective floor and refractive spheres are simply white and yellow.
The tint colors of the 4x8 blocks change wildly depending on what other programs are running on the GPU.

The image should look like this:
[image: Correct render]

Pseudocode of the broken shader was something like

```
out vec3 FragColor; // Out pixel of fragment shader

void main() {
    for (int i=0; i<NumberOfPointLights; i++) {
        ... Lighting calculation code...
        FragColor += lighting;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<NumberOfSpotLights; i++) {
        ... Lighting calculation code...
        FragColor += lighting;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<NumberOfDirectionalLights; i++) {
        ... Lighting calculation code...
        FragColor += lighting;
    }
}
```

To fix the issue, I simply initialised a temporary variable to hold the output color, wrote to that during lighting calculations and then wrote that to the fragment output at the end. As follows:

```
out vec3 FragColor; // Out pixel of fragment shader

void main() {
    vec3 outcolor = vec3(0);
    for (int i=0; i<NumberOfPointLights; i++) {
        ... Lighting calculation code...
        outcolor += lighting;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<NumberOfSpotLights; i++) {
        ... Lighting calculation code...
        outcolor += lighting;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<NumberOfDirectionalLights; i++) {
        ... Lighting calculation code...
        outcolor += lighting;
    }

    FragColor = outcolor;
}
```

I was surprised this worked as I assumed that this behaviour is assumed by default. That the writing to the fragment output doesn't actually write to VRAM each time, only at the end. I was under the impression that a fragment output variable is read from after shader execution, hence why its global.

#### Suspicions and Questions

1. From my research, I read that the 4x8 pixel groups is the size of one "work-group" or "core" on an nVidia GPU (which I am using) while AMD use 8x8 pixel work-groups. So Something is causing random work-groups' output color to be permanently affected until it is reassigned to a different location on screen.
2. The fact that the colours change depending on what else is using the GPU tells me that either the GPU has a very complicated memory allocation scheme and it's reading from other programs' memory (which I doubt) or that the shader is getting uninitialised memory every frame. But surely the same memory for the texture is written over each time?
3. Writing to the fragment out variable writes to VRAM each time, writing to it too many times per work-group causes the work-group to bail leaving mixed results behind. This would explain why a temporary/local variable works.
4. As I am always using += (read then write) The temporary variable initialisation acts as a explicit instruction to start with the color black and add to it, while writing to the fragment out directly adds to the last color of that pixel. If this where the case though, why did it work correctly on a higher-end PC?

Other details

My old laptop is using a GT540m with Optimus technology with integrated Intel 3000 graphics (which isn't being used here)
My newer desktop PC is using a GTX1070.
Both GPUs use very little VRAM during running the application, less than 100MB.
Shader is being compiled using `#version 400 core`

Comment: Sorry, I'm probably missing something here but... in the first (failing) code example where is `FragColor` initialized?

Comment: Adding to the previous comment. The initial value of an output variable is undefined if not initialized explicitly. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29206537/99279

Comment: That helps a lot @sterin, that is another pattern the broken shader does. So what you are both saying is that the default value of a fragment out is essentially random and i cannot trust that it is 0,0,0 by default. This is backed up by another quick test I just did where instead of the second (fixed) code. I just set a default value value to the fragment out and it worked.

Comment: That's correct.  Also found [this on the Khronos wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Fragment_shader_outputs) -- "Output variables from the fragment shader do not have to be written. However, unwritten outputs will have undefined values. This is OK if the current Framebuffer Draw Buffer setting would discard that value (by using GL_NONE)."

Answer (score 1):

This is a driver bug. There's nothing more to look into here.

Output variables can be read from and written to. This is part of GLSL. So it seems the driver just screwed up that implementation of it.